# React native render image from cameraRoll Uri

Tags: react-native, expo, camera-roll

I take a picture and saved it with cameraRoll, then I navigate with cameraroll uri as parameter so I can render the image in next view, but when the next view loads with no error, but image did not render:

```
      componentWillMount(){

      const params = this.props.navigation.state
      console.log('Params: ')
      console.log(params.params)
      let imageURL = params.params
      this.setState({imageUri:{
          uri: imageURL
        }
      });

    }

<View style={styles.container}>     
    <Image style={{flex: 1,flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', justifyContent: 'center'}} source={this.state.imageUri}/>             
</View>
```

style:

```
container:{ flex:1, justifyContent:'flex-start',alignItems:'center'},
```

This is the uri from imageUrl:
content://media/external/images/media/21680

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is the one and only time you should be modifying/initializing `state` directly ([docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html#docsNav)).
Any changes to `imageUri` should be made by calling `this.setState({imageUri: {uri: imageURL}})`.

Instead of

```
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   const params = this.props.navigation.state
   console.log('Params: ')
   console.log(params.params)
   let imageURL = params.params
   this.setState({imageUri: {
     uri: imageURL
   }});
 }
```

You should have

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   const params = this.props.navigation.state
   console.log('Params: ')
   console.log(params.params)
   let imageURL = params.params
   state = {imageUri: {
     uri: imageURL
   }};
 }
```

Comment: It keeps showing the same err, I update the code, its not showing the error msg, but image its not rendering.

Comment: That may be because your `imageUri` is an object wrapping the URI you are wanting to access. Try passing `this.state.imageUri.uri` into your source prop.

Comment: Try setting a fixed height and width, maybe it will solve the issue. `Note that for network and data images, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image!` according to [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html)